# Downloading files of certain type from s3 using CLI, without including files from subfolders

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm aware the you can copy files from s3 to local directories by using the aws CLI. In this use case below downloading only files containing .jpg extensions:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket myfolder --exclude '*' --include '*.jpg' --recursive
```

But using this approach (or using `sync`), will download all jpg files in sub buckets of s3://mybucket.

I could `ls` to get a list of files from the specific directory I'm looking at and then loop through the list, downloading each one individually, but this does cause multiple connections to be made and more lines of code.

Is there a means to grab all files of a given file type in a single command from a specific bucket, ignoring sub-buckets?

edit note:
By removing '--recursive'
I am hit with a
`fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "mybucket" does not exist`

Comment: Remove `--recursive`..?

Comment: I hit an error message in that case, see edited note above

Comment: Have you tried adding '/' after myBucket and remove recursive? `aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ myfolder --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg"`

Comment: I have. It will return all files when I'm using `--recursive` using the same path (including the / character), but when not using `--recursive` it throws the error, without making any edits to the path whatsoever